# xTable doesn't produce a table in R markdown

Tags: r, pdf, markdown, r-markdown, xtable

I am trying to get xtable to insert a table into an R markdown pdf document I'm working on. For some reason, I can't even get the examples from the documentation to reproduce. Instead, the output puts each individual cell on a new line. I've included a screen shot of a portion of my pdf. What am I doing wrong?? Do I need to update a package somewhere? I downloaded xTable today.

````
```{r, echo=FALSE, results = "asis"}
library(xtable)
data(tli)
print(xtable(tli[1:10,]), type = "html", floating = FALSE, include.rownames = T)
```
````

Sample of bad pdf

[image: Sample of bad pdf]

Comment: you should be using `type = "latex"` or leave out `type` entirely since the default is latex.. does that give what you want?

Comment: @rawr is right - as a side note, if you want table output that's automatically in the same format as your RMarkdown document output, you can use `knitr::kable`. It isn't as pretty, but it saves you from having to specify types or remembering to use the `results = "asis"' argument.

Comment: If you use `knitr::kable`, you can add relatively complex formatting without too much pain by using the [`kableExtra` package](http://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/).

Comment: Oh, thank goodness! Leaving type out worked! I needed more customization than kable offered for the tables I intended to generate.

Comment: @MeghanFranklin try the [htmlTable](https://github.com/gforge/htmlTable) package then. it is very customizable and was designed to mimic xtable, so you might be familiar with the syntax already